# ScriptManager Assembly load error in ASP.NET MVC Website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, scriptmanager

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 webapp which I have added an aspx web form to so that I can display the Microsoft Report Viewer control.  Everything works fine except when I add a ScriptManager tag so that I can set the timeout options.  I then get the following error -

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The web form HTML is as follows -

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ReportViewer.aspx.cs" Inherits="App.Web.ReportViewer" %>
<%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Report Viewer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="srtReportScriptManager"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rpvReportViewer" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" 
        Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" ProcessingMode="Remote" 
        WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt"
        PromptAreaCollapsed="True" ShowPromptAreaButton="False" Height="100%" 
        SizeToReportContent="True" Width="100%">
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```